# What happens if a browser that doesn't support HTML 5 encounters an HTML 5 website?

Tags: html

If you visit a site that uses Flash, and you don't have Flash installed on your browser, a message will be shown to you to install Flash. A similar procedure happens when Silverlight is involved instead of Flash.

What happens if a browser does not support HTML 5? Will I have to install something to get HTML 5 support in that case? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Insilico . i know all you say , i just ask a question , every man know that thay are different

Comment: @In silico: Yes, we can tell that from your comment. He wants to know if he gets an error message when he's using HTML5 in a non-HTML5-capable browser, just like he's getting an error when trying to use Flash where Flash isn't installed or Silverlight where Silverlight isn't installed.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar , exactly and maybe because I am new in English ,my question in not understandable enough.anyway thanks

Comment: @Ali Foroughi: I've edited your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Ali Foroughi: Don't worry about it. Human languages tend to not be very precise. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Browsers will ignore elements it doesn't support and it won't apply css styles to those elements either. You won't get any explicit message that the browser doesn't support HTML5. You can, as the page author, provide your own message if the browser doesn't depending on the circumstance. You can, for example, provide a message that will display to the user inside a video or audio tag.

Comment: Most browsers will allow you to style unrecognised elements (the primary exception being Internet Explorer, but even that can be made to do so with a hack).

Answer (score 1):

Well what happened earlier, wenn browsers supported HTML3 and you used HTML4? Nothing really, and that's what's going to happen for HTML5.

Flash and Silverlight are handled using browser plugins, so the browser can warn you if the plugin is not installed. HTML5 is not a plugin, so what you could do is to use JavaScript and check for the browser version.

Answer (score 1):

Users won't get a message if their browser doesn't support certain html5.

What you could do is check what html5 or css3 you need, and look at http://caniuse.com/ wich browsers are compatible with those functions and then use a script to give older browser users a notification to update to a newer browser.

Answer (score 1):

@Ali Foroughi I didn't notice a clear cut work around if you have HTML 5 elements in a website and how to get older browsers namely IE 8 and older to display the new HTML5 elements. Other answers are true that the HTML5 element won't display correctly or at all but what can be done about this.

There a couple things you can do to either "teach" older browsers to handle HTML5 correctly either by CSS, JavaScript, or an HTML5Shiv. These methods are explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_browsers.asp/%22HTML5%20Browser%20Support%22).

Of course these can't be implemented by the end user but by the websites designer/developer.

Was searching for the answer as to a work around in case someone has an older browser and HTML5 elements are used. I figured if there are work around's for certain CSS styling by using some sort of webkit in the CSS file surely there is for HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

> but what happen if a browser does not support HTML 5 ?

Exactly the same as what you described:

> If you see when a site uses flash technology ,and you have not flash
>   component installed on you browser, a message will be shown to you to
>   install flash(same as silverlight)

This feature detection has absolutely nothing to do with HTML5. It's the implementation of the `<object>` tag that allows you to specify an url to download the component from if the browser hasn't installed it. It is a browser dependent implementation though.